# Custom Login page in SharePoint 2013 with FBA autentication

Tags: customization, sharepoint-2013, fba

How can I customize the default login page in SharePoint 2013 with FBA authentication, but will not create a new login page, I want to modify the page that already exists.

Comment: It is late but will help future. http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991205/Branding-Default-Login-Page-for-Form-Based-Authent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The deafult login page is located here: **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\LOGIN\default.aspx**. You can modify that in Visual Studio. I know you said that you didn't want to create a new one but you could make a copy of the deafult one, add that to a new project and make your changes to the copy. That way you will preserve the default login page if you need to revert back.